# How tightly is the rural/urban population ratio correlated with a state's red/blue status?

Tags: united-states, parties, demographics

Having lived in a few areas in the U.S., I've noticed that urban cities are often (if not always) left-leaning (blue) and rural areas are right-leaning (red).

Setting aside the handful of "swing states", how much influence does the ratio of urban to rural population affect a state's overall political majority status? I assume someone has studied this, but I have yet to find anything so far.

Comment: Rather than asking "how much influence" (which may lead to subjective responses), consider asking the "what is the relationship of Urban/Rural population ratio and the political leanings within each state"

Comment: perhaps resolving the Urban v Rural ration to a simple **known** statistic like population density

Comment: Interesting read: https://www.citylab.com/equity/2016/11/how-americas-metro-areas-voted/508355/

Comment: @SJuan76 - thank you, this is the kind of thing I was interested in reading about

Comment: It certainly works like that in Britain. Rural "shire-counties" are Conservative-leaning, urban areas Labour-leaning. The only difference I note is that in Britain, as in most countries, other than America, left is red, right is blue.

Comment: Rather than asking about states you should ask about counties, as it makes sense to talk about urban vs rural counties, but not about urban vs rural states.

Comment: This blog post plots voting against population density for counties. Unfortunately it doesn't make the raw data available. http://davetroy.com/posts/the-real-republican-adversary-population-density

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using data from the 2016 Presidential election on Wikipedia and [data from Iowa State Uni](https://www.icip.iastate.edu/tables/population/urban-pct-states) on urban/rural ratio

[image]

There is a good correlation. I've drawn a least squares linear regression line. The product momement correlation is 0.57; r²=0.32 so about ⅓ of the variation in voting can be explained by variation the urban percentage.

My graph can be found [online](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/usj82784).

Outliers are always interesting. At the top right, DC has a completely urban population. Maine and Vermont are Blue states with a rural population. Utah is a largely urban state but very red (it would have been even further down had I used 2012 data)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer conditioned on Population density vs Gallup party affiliation (2015)**

[image: Gallup Poll (2015)]

Source:  [Gallup](https://news.gallup.com/poll/188969/red-states-outnumber-blue-first-time-gallup-tracking.aspx).

2013 estimate of population by the United States Census Bureau. [Wikipedia list of U.S. states by population density](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_by_population_density)

Of the top ten most heavily populated states 7 of 10 were Democratic.
Of the  ten least heavily populated states 8 of 10 were Republican.

Comment: What's the source of that image? What does "lean" mean? I'm surprised some states, eg Texas, is labeled "lean" where I'd think it was solid.

Comment: "Gallup considers states to be solidly favoring one party when they have a greater-than 10-percentage-point advantage over the other in party affiliation among the state's adult population. "Leaning" states are those in which one party has an advantage of more than five points but less than 10 points. Competitive states show the parties within five points of each other." - from Gallup citation